# How to check if a range contains unique values?

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have this array of dataset

```
apple       indonesia   25
apple       malaysia    21
apple       korea       32
orange      japan       27
grape       malaysia    12
strawberry  hongkong    56
durian D24  thailand    22
durian D24  China       72
grape       hongkong    120
```

I can select a range.

```
Dim rng1 as range
dim rng2 as range

set rng1=range(cells(1,3), cells(9,3))
set rng2=range(cells(1,2), cells(9,2))
```

rng1 contains no duplicates (all unique) but rng2 contains some duplicates (not unique)

I need something like

```
if rng1 is unique=true then
```

Comment: rng1 and rng2 also contains empty cells. Is that on intention? Did you consider to use a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, should be 9 rows not 10. A typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my comment you could use a [dictionary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) in the following way

```
Function isUnique(rg As Range) As Boolean

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim sngCell As Range

    Set dict = New Dictionary

    For Each sngCell In rg
        If Not dict.Exists(sngCell.Value) Then
            dict.Add sngCell.Value, sngCell.Value
        End If
    Next

    If rg.Cells.Count = dict.Count Then
        isUnique = True
    Else
        isUnique = False
    End If

End Function
```

And how to use the function

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range


    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(10, 3))
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(10, 2))

    If isUnique(rng1) Then
        MsgBox "Is unique"
    Else
        MsgBox "Is not unique"
    End If

End Sub
```

Based on @Jeeped's comment an [improvement](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Assigning_a_Value) for the `For loop`

```
For Each sngCell In rg
    dict.Item(sngCell.Value) = sngCell.Value
Next
```

> Assigning a value to Key this way has an extra feature. If the Key
>   does not exist it automatically adds the Key and Item to the
>   dictionary. This would be useful where you had a list of sorted items
>   and only wanted the last entry for each one.

And [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/identifying_unique_values_in_an_array_or_range/) you can find another solution for this question (example 4)

Comment: fwiw, the dictionary overwrite shorthand add method is slightly faster and doesn't require `Exists(...)`. `dict.item(sngCell.Value) = sngCell.Value`

Comment: @Jeeped: Thanks, good tip. I should read my own links, because it says there _Change value at key. Automatically adds if the key does not exist._

Comment: I'm a new user and am not entirely familiar with the function. I only understad the 2nd part. So I would need to first write the first part down in my code, and then the 2nd part would work?

Comment: Yes, that's the genral idea. Have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-sub/)

Comment: Hi Storax, is it possible to insert two functions? For instance     If rg.Cells.Count = dict.Count Then
        isUnique = True
    Elseif rg.Cells.Count = 10 and dict.Count= 1 then 
      isConstant=true
else   
        isUnique = False
    End If

Comment: Feel free to do that but I think the original question is answered. If you need to tweak the function, go ahead and try something on your own. If you get stuck doing that open a new question with the problem you have.

Comment: It's okay storax. I've found a way around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For record numbers on a sheet, I use the `MODE` function. It returns the value which is most often repeated, or `#N/A` if there is no duplicted value, i.e. all values are unique:

```
Function isUnique(rng As Range)
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Mode (rng)
   isUnique = Err <> 0
   Err.Clear
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I looped over the cells in the range and checked and used the countif-function:
If Not WorksheetFunction.Countif(range,range.Cells(i,j).Value)=1 Then Goto Abort
Worked well

Answer (score 0):

If you have MS 365 at your disposal you might use the following udf:

```
Function OnlyUniques(rng As Range) As Boolean
'Purp: check if there are only uniques in given range
'Auth: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
    OnlyUniques = UBound(WorksheetFunction.Unique(rng)) = rng.Rows.Count
End Function
```